# How to check user input with if command

Tags: c#, if-statement, input, key, chars

Not sure if I'm overlooking something really simple but I'm trying to make a program that allows a user to enter 1 of 2 letters and then run code based on the input. Seems simple enough but I've run into several errors with all the ways I thought this could work. Here is the code:

```
string name = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Is " + name + " ok?");
Console.WriteLine("\n(Y)es\n(N)o");
char ansys = Console.ReadKey();
if (ansys = ConsoleKey.Y)
    Console.Clear();
else
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter letters only");
}
```

I added in the else portion (unfinished)just to get an idea if If i'm going the right direction with the intended goal as well. Would I be able to make an else statement that triggers if neither Y or N is pressed this way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you are making an assignment, not comparing:

```
if (ansys.Key = ConsoleKey.Y)
```

is wrong, use:

```
if (ansys.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
```

`==` is comparison, `=` is assignment. Don't confuse them, it may cause serious problems.

For you question, if you simply add an `else if` statement checking for "No" answer, then else statement won't be triggered if Y or N is pressed. If at least if statement is executed, else statement won't be executed.

Your code should look like:

```
if (ansys == ConsoleKey.Y) {
    // code if yes
}
else if (ansys == ConsoleKey.N) {
    // code if no
}
else {
    // code if neither
}
```

**Edit:**
Since my primary language is not C#, I looked at documentation to check my answer. I figured out that if you use `ReadKey()` it does not return a `ConsoleKey`, it returns `struct ConsoleKeyInfo`. You need to use `Key` member of the `ConsoleKeyInfo` to access the pressed key. Please re-check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
cki = Console.ReadKey();

if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
{
    Console.Clear();
}
else if (cki.Key == Console.N)
{
    Console.Clear();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter letters only");
}
```

You can find th examples here: [ReadKey - examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string name = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Is " + name + " ok?");
Console.WriteLine("\n(Y)es\n(N)o");
var ansys = Console.ReadKey();
if (ansys.KeyChar == 'y' || ansys.KeyChar == 'Y')
{
    //Handle yes case
}
if (ansys.KeyChar == 'n' || ansys.KeyChar == 'N')
{
    //Handle no case
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter letters only");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (couldnt test it)

- This will ask for the name until the confirmation answer is `Y`
- If the input when asked Y or N is another thing, it will ask again for the name confirmation.

  ```
  string name = "";
  while (name.equals(""))
  {
      name = (Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Is " + name + " ok?");

      String answer = "";
      while(answer.equals(""))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("\n(Y)es\n(N)o");
          char ansys = Console.ReadKey();
          if (ansys == ConsoleKey.Y || ansys == ConsoleKey.N)
          {
              answer = ansys.ToString();
              Console.Clear();
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine("Enter letters only!!");
          }
      }
      if(!answer.equals("Y"))
          name = "";
  }
  ```

Im not sure if `ansys.ToString()` is a valid method, and if that returns the "Y" string in case the key pressed was Y